# If $ \operatorname{Ass}(M)= \operatorname{Assh}(M)$, then $M$ is a Cohen-Macaulay $R$-module?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, cohen-macaulay

Let $R$ be a local commutative Noetherian ring and $M$ a finitely generated $R$-module. We denote by $ \operatorname{Assh}(M)=\{ \mathfrak{p}\in  \operatorname{Ass}(M) \mid \dim R/\mathfrak{p}=\dim M\}.$ Assume that $\operatorname{Ass}(M)=\operatorname{Assh}(M).$ Can we conclude that $M$ is a Cohen-Macaulay $R$-module?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What's $\text{Ass}(M)$ ? I'm at work so I can't Google it.

Comment: The set $Ass(M)$ is the set of associated primes of $M.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not true. When $M=R/I$ for some ideal $I$, the condition $\operatorname{Assh}(R/I)=\operatorname{Ass}(R/I)$ means that the ideal $I$ is unmixed. This is a weaker condition than the Cohen-Macaulay property, for instance $k[x,y,z,t]/(x,y) \cap (z,t)$ satisfies your property, but it is not Cohen-Macaulay.

Comment: Thanks. If, in addition, we assume that $R$ is a Cohen-Macaulay ring, then is the above statement true?

Comment: No, in the example above $R$ is a polynomial ring